# Assigning class Instance to Interface

Tags: vb.net

Have two questions regarding the code below:

1. In the following code, the class Test implement the interface Test_Interafce. I have read in more than one articles that when a class implements an interface, we should assign the class instance to the interface. Going by that in the following code the statement `Dim t As New Test()` should be replaced by `Dim t As Test_Interface = New Test()`. However I do not understand the advantage or need for the same. When I instantiate the class Test by simply writing `Dim t As New Test()`, I am able to access all elements (even the procedures of the interface implemented by the class) through the instance "t" and the code seems to be working fine. So then why to assign a class instance to an interface?

Infact if I write `Dim t As Test_Interface = New Test()` then through "t" does not allow me to access the subroutine CHECK in the class Test. The error being displayed is: "CHECK is not a member of Test_Interface". So isnt that a disadvantage??!!

2. What is the use of the statement: `Throw New NotImplementedException()`. This statement comes automatically when I implement teh interface in a class/structure.

The code is found below:

```
Module Module1
    Interface Test_Interface
        Function Length(ByVal s As String) As Integer
        Sub Details(ByVal age As Integer, ByVal name As String)
    End Interface
    Sub Main()
        Dim t As New Test()  'Alternate definition: Dim t As Test_Interface = New Test()
        t.Details(31, "Mounisha")
        Console.WriteLine("Length of the string entered = {0}", t.Length("Hello"))
        t.check()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Class Test
    Implements Test_Interface
    Public Sub Details(age As Integer, name As String) Implements Test_Interface.Details
        Console.WriteLine("Age of person = {0}", age)
        Console.WriteLine("Name of person = {0}", name)
        'Throw New NotImplementedException() ----> what does this do?
    End Sub
    Public Function Length(s As String) As Integer Implements Test_Interface.Length
        Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", s)
        Return s.Length()
        'Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
    Sub check()
        Console.WriteLine("The sub can be accessed")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That interface is a *contract*: you know that if a Class implements the interface, it has to provide properties and methods defined by the Interface. Even when you don't know anything about that Class, you know you can call those methods or get/set those properties; you also know their return Type. -- `Throw New NotImplementedException()` is kind of a *placeholder*, it lets you know that the method is still not implemented if you call it and prevents a warning or build error, since, e.g., a Function must return a value, unless it throws an exception. [...]

Comment: Try to remove `Return` and then un-comment `Throw ...` . This all will come in handy and will be probably more clear when you define Generics with specific constraints. You'll be able to use different type of objects that implement the same Interface, just knowing about the Interface and nothing else. Or when you inject objects in other objects that only allow implementers of a specific Interface they know about. Or build Plug-Ins, or... may other uses.

Comment: Hi..any comments/answers on my first question?

Comment: It's in half of the first comment and all of the second comment.